# My oracle merge does not work

Tags: oracle, insert, merge, upsert

I am running 
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.5.0 - Prod.
I want to merge data from m2 into m1. I expect to see 3 records
in m1 after the merge, one for 'c' with a knt of 4, one for 'a' with a knt of 1
and one for 'b' with a knt of 1.

But I get everything. As if no checking for update or insert occurred.

See below.

Best regards,

Phil

```
 SQL> desc m1;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 K                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 V                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 KNT                                                NUMBER(4)

SQL> desc m2;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 K                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 V                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 KNT                                                NUMBER(4)

SQL> select * from m1;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from m2;

K      V             KNT
------ ------ ----------
a      aaa             0
b      bbb             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
a      aaa             0
b      bbb             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0


SQL> merge into m1 d
  2  using (select k,v,knt from m2) s

 SQL> desc m1;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 K                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 V                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 KNT                                                NUMBER(4)

SQL> desc m2;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 K                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 V                                                  VARCHAR2(6)
 KNT                                                NUMBER(4)

SQL> select * from m1;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from m2;

K      V             KNT
------ ------ ----------
a      aaa             0
b      bbb             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
a      aaa             0
b      bbb             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0


SQL> merge into m1 d
  2  using (select k,v,knt from m2) s
  3  on (d.k = s.k)
  4  when matched then
  5  update set d.knt = d.knt+1
  6  when not matched then
  7  insert(d.k,d.v,d.knt)
  8  values(s.k,s.v,s.knt)
  9  ;

SQL> select * from m1;

K      V             KNT
------ ------ ----------
b      bbb             0
b      bbb             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
c      ccc             0
a      aaa             0
a      aaa             0
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want a MERGE?  It sounds like you really want

```
INSERT INTO m2( k, v, knt )
  SELECT k, v, count(*)
    FROM m1
   GROUP BY k, v
```

A MERGE is a set-based operation.  The data in M2 is evaluated at the time the query is executed so your `USING` clause is not going to see the rows that are being inserted as part of the `MERGE`.  Since the `USING` clause returns 0 rows, all the data from `M1` is going to be inserted into `M2`.  The `WHEN MATCHED` clause is never going to be triggered.

Comment: Aha !!! Post at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables] indicates that I have to have distinct records to insert. Thus -- if I change my sql to  --- arrggh see my answer to my own question

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. It looks like I have to keep the records I am inserting 'distinct'.

So this works. .... kind of.

```
 merge into m1 d
 using (select distinct k,v,knt from m2) s
 on (d.k = s.k and d.v = s.v)
 when matched then
 update set d.knt = d.knt+1
 when not matched then
 insert(d.k,d.v,d.knt)
 values(s.k,s.v,s.knt)
```