# Can we run merge(Oracle) query more than once when source does not change

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the below query,

```
MERGE INTO table2 b
     USING (
         SELECT column1,column2,column3
         FROM table1
     ) a
     ON (a.column3 = 'UPDATE')
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
         INSERT (b.column1, b.column2) VALUES (a.column1,a.column2)
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET a.column1 = b.column1,a.column2=b.column2;
```

When the table2 is empty it is running succesfully for the first time. 
If i am running for the second time even though table1 data isn't changed i am getting the error as `unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables`..Is there a workaround for this error.

As mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables) , I tried putting the `Distinct` but it did not solve..

I think `rowid` should solve the purpose here..but not sure

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables)

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned in that thread and it does not work..Not sure if i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ON (a.column3 = 'UPDATE')` is not sufficient.

You need to state how the two tables relate to each other.  This is important so that:
- A given row in Table1 matches one row in Table2 *(UPDATE)*
- Or, a given row in Table1 has no match in Table2 *(INSERT)*

This means that the `ON` clause ***must*** match the two tables together 1:1 or 1:0.  Never many:many.  In the code below I will assume that `column1` is a unique identifier.  If that's the case it conforms to the 1:1 requirement.

If you don't have a way to uniquely identify each row in each table, then you need to change your data so that you can.

```
MERGE INTO
  table2 b
USING (
  SELECT column1,column2,column3
  FROM table1
) a
ON (
  b.column1 = a.column1
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (b.column1, b.column2) VALUES (a.column1,a.column2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b.column2 = a.column2;
```

Note that I don't use the `UPDATE` value here, as it doesn't *seem* necessary *(You may provide more info which explains why it is)*.

Instead, for every row in `table1`, this searches for a row in `table1` with the same value in `column1`.  If one is *NOT* found, the `INSERT` is executed.  If one *IS* found, then the update is executed.

What yours had been doing is saying that a match is found if (`a.column3 = 'UPDATE'`).  This meant that every row in `table2` was being matched against every `'UPDATE'` row in `table1` - making it try to update the same row in `table2` with the values from *many* rows in `table1`.

Then, also, every row where `a.column3 <> 'UPDATE'` would be inserted into `table2`.

Comment: I was about to write that 0:1 matching should also be mentioned when I decided to verify myself if Oracle MERGE had a WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE clause. I was surprised it turned out not to have one, all the more so since the [doc page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) says that the statement *‘lets you avoid multiple `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, **and `DELETE`** DML statements’*. But it goes on to reveal that there's actually no DELETE clause in Oracle MERGE! I wonder if you know of something I might be missing here. Otherwise the docs seem to be contradictory

Comment: @AndriyM there is a delete clause but it seems to be part of the UPDATE section and I've found it to be rather limited usefulness anyway.

Comment: @MikeMeyers: Ah, I overlooked that all right. Shows how carefully I was reading the article ("skimming it over" more likely). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much Dems, i figured out what is common between two tables and solved the problem..