# Oracle Code to insert data into table that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert data into a table in Oracle database. Data already exists, but not all of the data, and I can't just delete the data and reinsert it all. Is there a way to insert data into the table (without knowing what data I am missing). My script is running, but no data is actually inserting (and I do know there is data missing. I intentionally took data out to test its re-insertion.)

```
Insert into item (item, descr) 
select distinct a.SUBORD, a.SUBORD_DESCR FROM EXIDE.UDT_BOM a, item b 
where b.item = a.subord and not exists 
(select b.item from item b, exide.udt_bom a where a.subord = b.ITEM)
```

Comment: You should provide an example (current state of a row and how would you like it to look like after the update)

Comment: It is Oracle. What do you mean by current state of a row?

Comment: You're joining on `b.item = a.subord`, but also have that in the `not exists` as `a.subord = b.ITEM` - surely they can't both be true?

Comment: I do have the Commit statement after. The script does not return any rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow what you're doing, you can use the [`merge` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm) for this:

```
merge into item i
using (select subord, subord_descr from exide.udt_bom) u
on (i.item = u.subord)
when not matched then insert (item, descr) values (u.subord, u.subord_descr);
```

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2eb4/1).

This also has the advantage that if the `udt_bom` has new descriptions for existing items, you can update those in the `item` table too:

```
merge into item i
using (select subord, subord_descr from exide.udt_bom) u
on (i.item = u.subord)
when matched then update set descr = u.subord_descr
when not matched then insert (item, descr) values (u.subord, u.subord_descr);
```

[Another fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2eb4/2).

Comment: When I run the merge statement, I get a unique constraint, primary key violation. So it's still trying to insert items that already exist in the Item table.

Comment: What's your PK, `item`? You have the `matched` and `not matched` the right way round, right? (I think I do!). And all changes in other sessions are committed? Here's a [SQL Fiddle with a PK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/478be/1) to show it works; so I'm not sure what you're doing differently?

Comment: A new error has arisen that says "ORA30926: Unable to get a stable set of rows into the source tables"

Comment: Yeah. I tested out your SQL Fiddle that you had attached and saw that it works properly. After ensuring all was the same, the new error came up.

Comment: Your query "select subord, subord_descr from exide.udt_bom" has duplicate rows -- subord is not unique in it.

Comment: @user2529787 - so you have duplicates in `udt_bom` then I think? [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2337271/266304). If both `subord` and `subord_descr` are the same in multiple rows then I think you can just  make the `using` clause `select distinct`...

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So I need to remove duplicates for it to work properly?

Comment: I have made the change to say select distinct, but am still returning the same "Stable set of rows" error.

Comment: Do you have the same `subord` with different `subord_descr`? If so you'd need to decide which you'd want to use, and get the query inside the `using` clause to get a set of data which only has each `subord` once. (Options include picking the max, or the most recent if there's a date field, or the first by some other criteria - you'll have to judge based on the data).

Comment: I'm thinking that the subord_descr is causing my issue. When I remove it, the statement works. So it is a data problem on my end. Thank you guys so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many references to too many tables.  With the `not exists` clause, the query does not need explicit joins:

```
Insert into item(item, descr) 
    select distinct b.SUBORD, b.SUBORD_DESCR
    FROM EXIDE.UDT_BOM b
    where not exists (select i.item from item i where b.subord = i.ITEM);
```

If there are no duplicates, in `udt_bom`, I would get rid of the `distinct` as well.  And, queries are more readable when you use table abbreviations as aliases, rather than meaningless letters like `a`, `b`, and so on.

Comment: When I run the merge statement, I get a unique constraint, primary key violation. So it's still trying to insert items that already exist in the Item table.

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestions for replacing the letters with something more readable and understandable. Will be very helpful to me.

Comment: After checking some stuff, I found that some of my data is incorrect with subord_descr, so when I remove it, the script works. Thank you for you help, as well as the suggestions for query cleanup.