# Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, plsql

I am getting the error : unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables when I ran the below statement.

```
   merge into table_1 c
    using (select rep_nbr, T_nbr, SF from table_2) b
    on (c.rep_id=b.rep_nbr)
    when matched then
    update set 
    c.T_ID =b.T_nbr,
    c.SF=b.SF
    when not matched then
    insert(T_id, SF)
    values(null, null);
```

When i put distinct before the rep_nbr

```
merge into table_1 c
    using (select distinct rep_nbr,t_nbr,SF from table_2) b
    on (c.rep_id=b.rep_nbr)
    when matched then
    update set 
    c.T_ID =b.T_nbr,
    c.SF=b.SF
    when not matched then
    insert(T_id, SF)
    values(null, null);
```

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into c.rep_id.
I don't want to populate c.rep_id, i just need them to match and then update those records that matched.

Comment: So what prevents you to remove the last segment of the query?When not matched....

Comment: @mihai I guess it is not necessary to have that part. Will taking it out make a difference though?

Comment: If you need just the update yes.In your last query the prob is probably inserting null values into not null columns.

Comment: @mihai I took it out, now it says unable to get a stable set of rows

Comment: @mihai With distinct or without, I receive the same message.

Comment: See if this is of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you don't need MERGE, just an UPDATE. Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 
SET t1.t_id = (SELECT DISTINCT t2.t_nbr FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t1.rep_id = t2.rep_nbr),
    t1.sf = (SELECT DISTINCT t2.sf FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t1.rep_id = t2.rep_nbr),
WHERE t1.rep_id IN (SELECT rep_nbr FROM table_2)
```

But, however, in later versions of Oracle (from 10th or 11th) you can take out parts of merge, for example, take out WHEN NOT MATCHED part.

Answer (score 0):

remove part "with not matched then"

```
merge into table_1 c
    using (select distinct rep_nbr,t_nbr,SF from table_2) b
    on (c.rep_id=b.rep_nbr)
    when matched then
    update set 
    c.T_ID =b.T_nbr,
    c.SF=b.SF
```