# Merge tables based on column validation

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a temporary table that is reloaded periodicaly. The data within this table must go to a target table (exactly the same structure), but, if I have  duplicated values, it must check the last loaded data and update the target table.

Example:

```
TMP_DP_REGIAO

SG  NOME    LOADING_DATE
AM  RG_1102 19-FEB-14
RO  RG_1103 19-FEB-14
AP  RG_1104 19-FEB-14
TO  RG_1105 19-FEB-14
RO  RG_1106 19-FEB-14
```

After loaded, this data should go to `TB_DP_REGIAO` (that as I said, has the same structure).

The point is:

If `SG` in `TMP` already exists in `TB`, SQL must verify if this record in `TMP` has a greater `LOADING_DATE` than in `TB`. If so, update the `TB`. Otherwise, ignore it.

Can someone help on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL could fit your needs:

```
merge into TB_DP_REGIAO B
using TMP_DP_REGIAO P
on (P.SG = B.SG)
when matched then update set B.NOME = case when B.LOADING_DATE < P.LOADING_DATE then P.NOME else B.NOME end,
                             B.LOADING_DATE = case when B.LOADING_DATE < P.LOADING_DATE then P.LOADING_DATE else B.LOADING_DATE end
when not matched then insert(SG, NOME, LOADING_DATE) values(P.SG, P.NOME, P.LOADING_DATE)
;
```

Comment: When I run it next day, when P.LOADING_DATE is one day ahead, I get a `SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables`. It says for me to `Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.`. Do you know what is happening? The query seemed to be pretty much ok for me.

Comment: According to this other SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables), this may be due to `TMP_DP_REGIAO` having duplicates on `SG` field (I supposed `SG` was the key). Try to check for duplicates...