# Redirect duplicate rows to update while insert

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a insert statement on table "test". PK on column x in the table "test".
Now while inserting if duplicate row comes then the same row should get updated instead insert.
How can i achieve this.
Is it possible by `dup_val_on_index`?

Please help.

Comment: I guess you could use the MERGE statement for this.

Comment: First define "duplicate". Then check Oracle's [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) that can do either insert or update depending if the row already exists in the target table.

Comment: here both insert and updae is on the same table.if passible can you please provide me an example

Answer (score 0):

First create a copy of the above table without any `KEY` Columns and follow

Step 1: `truncate` the table first whenever you encounter a bunch of insert statement comes

Step 2: `INSERT` the above truncated tables

Step 3: Execute the `MERGE` statement like below

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_MAIN M
   USING TABLE_MAIN_COPY C
   ON (m.id = c.id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET M.somecol = c.somecol
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (m.id, m.somecol)
     VALUES (c.id, c.somecol);
```

You may incur error while on merger `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` when there is two or more rows while on update.

you may avoid that using the `GROUP` function related to id or like [ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables)