# ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables in the following query

Tags: oracle

```
MERGE INTO tbl_brk_sch_cat_mappin_temp bsc
USING  lookup l
ON (l.lookup_id = bsc.catery_id) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET bsc.new_category=l.longname where  bsc.created_date=to_date('10/30/2015','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

I've ran tbl_brk_sch_cat_mappin_temp it has data and also I've ran the 'lookup' table  which also has data.

Why would this error come and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2337465/5280641

Comment: I have already tried that example it's not working in my case , it gives merged successfully message but data is not merged or updated into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when you have more than one row in the source data (in your case, the lookup table) that matches against a single row in your target table (in your case, the tbl_brk_sch_cat_mappin_temp table) based on your join condition.

In this scenario, you're asking Oracle to update a single row with two different values, which doesn't really make sense to do.

To fix the issue, you need to either correct the data in your source table or fix the join condition so that each row in your target table matches against a single row in your source table.

Comment: we are updating a single row with single value at a time according to our join condition. first it checks if the join condition match and then it updates. previously it used to work.

@Boneist

Comment: so what does the following query return? `select bsc.catery_id, count(*) from tbl_brk_sch_cat_mappin_temp bsc inner join lookup l on (l.lookup_id = bsc.catery_id) group by bsc.catery_id having count(*) > 1;`

Comment: we get 41 rows with multiple counts @boneist

Comment: So that's your problem then. If, for example, `bsc.catery_id = 1` matches with two rows where `l.lookup_id = 1`, one of which has `l.longname = 'name1'` and the other has `l.longname = 'name2'`, what is bsc.new_category meant to be set to? name1 or name2? It clearly can't be set to be both at the same time! So, you need to make sure that the source dataset only returns one row per join condition (i.e. in your case, you need to make sure that lookup_id is unique in the source dataset. Maybe you need an extra predicate in your join condition, or maybe you need to do an aggregate/distinct)

Comment: Thank You so much it worked for me there was a duplicate entry we got it corrected @Boneist

Comment: I'm glad you managed to get it sorted. If the table isn't supposed to have duplicate entries, you should consider adding in a unique constraint to prevent the issue from occurring again.