# Implement type II SCD in Oracle trigger with using merge

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger, scd

For the life of me I can't’ get the following query to work…essentially it’s a modification of the following ticket:
[Trigger with Merge statement in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824580/trigger-with-merge-statement-in-oracle).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE_UPDATE
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON DIM_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
IF INSERTING OR UPDATING
THEN
    MERGE INTO DIM_TABLE T_1
          USING( SELECT COL_1, max(VALID_FROM) AS LAST_DATE FROM 
DIM_TABLE
          GROUP BY COL_1) T_2
          ON (T_1. COL_1= T_2. COL_1)

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (T_1. VALID_FROM) VALUES(SYSDATE)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET T_1.VALID_UNTIL = T_2.LAST_DATE
      WHERE T_1. VALID_UNTIL is null 
      AND T_1. VALID_FROM <> T_2.LAST_DATE;
   COMMIT;
 END IF; 
END;
```

Desired functionality: a value is entered into the database (COL_1).
If the column does not have a match then the VALID_FROM date is entered as sysdate. If there is a match then the script should update the VALID_UNTIL value for the previous row (which was null until now because it was still valid).

I keep getting the following errors:
deadlock and maximum level of recursions exceeded (50)

Comment: You're attempting to merge into the same table the trigger is against - that could throw a mutating table error, but in this case it seems to be bypassing that - I guess through the autonomous hack - and instead recursively updates (the merge causes an insert/update, which fires the trigger, which causes an insert/update, which...). The 'ticket' you refer to involves different tables. I'd step back to your actual business requirement and approach it a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @hol, @Alex Poole, I think I cracked it.
I'm using a trigger for inserting data into the VALID_FROM every time anything gets added:

```
 CREATE TABLE "DIM_TEST" (  "COL_1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "VALID_UNTIL" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"DIM_TEST_PK" NUMBER, "VALID_FROM" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT NULL) 

  create or replace TRIGGER T_DIM_TEST_DATE_INSERT
  BEFORE INSERT ON DIM_TEST
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    :new.VALID_FROM := sysdate;
  END;
```

and for the part which updates the previous row VALID_FROM when a duplicate is added I have the following trigger:

```
 create or replace TRIGGER TABLE_UPDATE
 after INSERT or update
 ON DIM_TEST
 FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
 PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
 BEGIN
 IF INSERTING
 THEN
    MERGE INTO DIM_TEST T_1
    USING (select :new.COL_1 from DUAL) T_2
      ON (T_1.COL_1 = :new.COL_1)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET T_1.VALID_UNTIL = (SYSDATE)
  WHERE T_1. VALID_UNTIL is null;
  --AND T_1. VALID_FROM <> (SELECT max(VALID_FROM) FROM DIM_TEST);
 END IF;  
COMMIT;
END;
```

The only downside is that if an existing row is updated to be a duplicate then the second trigger will not fire because of the IF INSERTING clause...when I change it to
IF INSERTING or UPDATING then it will generate an infinite loop...but I can restrict users only to inserts so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I really struggle getting your requirement. To me it seems that you want `VALID_FROM` to be either `sysdate` or the max value for each `COL_1`.

That I would do by making use of `:NEW` to manipulate current row

```
set linesize 250
drop table dim_Table;
create table dim_table (col_1 varchar2(50), valid_from timestamp);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE_UPDATE
  before INSERT OR UPDATE ON DIM_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_valid_from date;
BEGIN
  select max(valid_from) 
    into l_valid_from
   from  dim_table t1
   where t1.col_1 = :new.col_1;
   if l_valid_from is null then
     :new.valid_from := sysdate;
   else
     :new.valid_from := l_valid_from;
   end if;
END;

insert into dim_table (col_1) values ('TEST1');
select * from dim_table;
exec dbms_lock.sleep(1);
insert into dim_table (col_1) values ('TEST1');
select * from dim_table;
exec dbms_lock.sleep(1);
insert into dim_table (col_1) values ('TEST2');
select * from dim_table;
exec dbms_lock.sleep(1);
insert into dim_table (col_1) values ('TEST1');
select * from dim_table;
exec dbms_lock.sleep(1);
insert into dim_table (col_1) values ('TEST2');
select * from dim_table;
```

Output:

```
Table dropped.
Table created.
Trigger created.
1 row created.

COL_1                                              VALID_FROM                                        
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
1 row selected.
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
1 row created.

COL_1                                              VALID_FROM                                        
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        

2 rows selected.
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
1 row created.

COL_1                                              VALID_FROM                                        
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST2                                              30/04/2019 09:13:12.000000                        

3 rows selected.
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
1 row created.

COL_1                                              VALID_FROM                                        
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST2                                              30/04/2019 09:13:12.000000                        
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        

4 rows selected.
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
1 row created.

COL_1                                              VALID_FROM                                        
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST2                                              30/04/2019 09:13:12.000000                        
TEST1                                              30/04/2019 09:13:10.000000                        
TEST2                                              30/04/2019 09:13:12.000000                        

5 rows selected.
```