# How to convert mysql query to oracle ( using UPDATE and INNER JOIN 2 times with 3 tables)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have the following MySQL query:

```
UPDATE spot ST 
INNER JOIN tag_mapping_spot c ON c.spot_id = ST.spot_id 
INNER JOIN def_table b ON b.tag_id = c.tag_id 
SET ST.spot_name = b.tag_ja
```

Recently I move to oracle and want to convert this query to oracle version. I searched and tried

```
UPDATE ( SELECT spot.spot_name as f1, def_table.tag_ja as f2 
        FROM spot 
        INNER JOIN tag_mapping_spot 
        ON tag_mapping_spot.spot_id = spot.spot_id
        INNER JOIN def_table
        ON def_table.tag_id = tag_mapping_spot.tag_id
        ) j
SET j.f2 = j.f1
```

and

```
MERGE into spot
USING tag_mapping_spot
ON (tag_mapping_spot.spot_id = spot.spot_id)
USING def_table
ON (def_table.tag_id = tag_mapping_spot.tag_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET spot.spot_name = def_table.tag_jae
```

But none of them work. How should I deal with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can use for UPDATE :

```
UPDATE spot s
SET s.spot_name = (SELECT def_table.tag_ja as f2
                      FROM def_table
                      INNER JOIN tag_mapping_spot
                      ON tag_mapping_spot.tag_id = def_table.tag_id
                      WHERE tag_mapping_spot.SPOT_ID = s.SPOT_ID)
WHERE s.spot_id in (select spot_id from tag_mapping_spot );
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b96f9bd7bd26b27b61c17c38d56fec6a)

And here is a nice script to show you how to use MERGE:
[SCRIPT](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_PC76LRDFFAVI6P6LMCWJLBOP2.html)

And in case you have double entry in all tables then check this [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9b8dae1a19a191f94f6e89c2717ce87f)

```
UPDATE spot s
SET s.spot_name = (SELECT max(def_table.tag_ja) as f2
                      FROM def_table
                      INNER JOIN tag_mapping_spot
                      ON tag_mapping_spot.tag_id = def_table.tag_id
                      WHERE tag_mapping_spot.SPOT_ID = s.SPOT_ID)
WHERE s.spot_id in (select spot_id from tag_mapping_spot );
```

Comment: Your DEMO is incorrect. I just fixed the sample data. Can you take a look ```https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5adccad1169c125715809521f2498b44```

Comment: I have updated my answer and corrected the code. It will now work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `inline view` within a MERGE statement :

```
 MERGE INTO spot s
 USING ( SELECT distinct st.spot_name, c.spot_id , b.tag_ja
           FROM spot st 
           JOIN tag_mapping_spot c ON c.spot_id = st.spot_id 
           JOIN def_table b ON b.tag_id = c.tag_id ) tt
    ON (s.spot_id = tt.spot_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET s.spot_name = tt.tag_ja;
```

Comment: I got the following error: "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table."

Comment: Vote up! Just a notice, this will not work in case you have a double id entry in some table like for example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e109909b5d9f06f03bee9e367a77b304

Comment: Thank you, sorry not to mention but my ```spot_id``` column is unique and auto-increment so there is no double id entry in my table

Comment: UPDATE: I tried your query with huge amount of data (10000) and It's return this error "ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables" . What 's that mean ??

Comment: it's not a flaw for the statement, but related to the data structure within the table which comes from the inline query after `USING` clause. I added an extra `distinct`  against the issue. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337465/5841306).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query as follow:

```
update spot set spot_name = 
 (SELECT def_table.tag_ja as f2 
        FROM spot 
        INNER JOIN tag_mapping_spot 
        ON tag_mapping_spot.spot_id = spot.spot_id
        INNER JOIN def_table
        ON def_table.tag_id = tag_mapping_spot.tag_id)
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Tried but not working . I got following error : "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: it may be possible that id column is not unique in your tables