# Update statement error - Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml

Tags: oracle, sql-merge

Hi I am getting syntax error while running the below historical statement in oracle db , can you please let me know how to fix the below error ?

```
MERGE INTO d_prod_fld dp USING
  (SELECT stg_prod_fld_id,
          prod_cd_id,
          country_name
   FROM stg_prod_fld_delta pd
   LEFT OUTER JOIN d_loc dl ON (dl.prod_cd_num = lpad(pd.prod_cd_id, 3, '0'))
   WHERE pd.efft_to > trunc(sysdate+1)
     AND pd.prod_cd_id IS NOT NULL 
  ) stg 
ON (dp.cd_id = stg.stg_prod_fld_id) 
WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE SET dl.prod_country=stg.country_name;
```

- d_prod_fld - target dimension table ,
- stg_prod_fld_delta - stage table ,
- d_loc - look up table

basically when i tried to run the above query in sandbox it is running fine ,but when i tried to run in actual development environment it is showing the above error -

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>
> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables 30926. 00000 - "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
>
> *Cause: A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
>
> *Action: Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Comment: Simple "solution" might be using `select distinct stg_prod_fld_id, ...`. See if it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables)

Comment: Hi Littlefoor i have tried using distinct the result expected is 614 but after running the update 1364 rows but when i do the  select 614 only but why it is updating 1364 rows ?